# magento redirect is not changing to 301

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

Hi does anyone know why this is not redirecting with a 301? it keeps returning 302

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                   ->setRedirect($newUrl,301)
                   ->sendResponse();
```

I even tried to change it from the abstract file (for testing only)

```
public function setRedirect($url, $code = 301)
{
    $this->canSendHeaders(true);
    $this->setHeader('Location', $url, true)
         ->setHttpResponseCode($code);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the sendHeaders function in Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract and in my case I was trying to redirect from a 404 page, so the headers were changing more times and that was confusing Magento!

Clearing the headers before setting the redirect was the solution for me!

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setRedirect($url, 301)->sendResponse();
```